# worksheet_SelectionChange for a specific column

Tags: excel, events, vba

I have a worksheet that contains invoice numbers in column D.  I'd like to copy the invoice number to another worksheet ("Details") when one is selected.  I've added the "If IsNumeric" condition to make sure that only cells containing an invoice # will be copied over.  The code seems to do nothing, can anyone help point me in the right direction?

`Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Sheets("Detail").Range("A5").Value = Target.Value
       Application.EnableEvents = True
            Sheets("Detail").Activate
        End If
    End If
End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Rather than:</strike>

```
IsNumeric(Target.Address)
```

try

```
IsNumeric(Target)
```

**EDIT#1:**

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            Target.Copy Sheets("Detail").Range("A5")
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

You need to re-enable events within the same **IF**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        On Error Resume Next
            If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Sheets("Detail").Range("A5").Value = Target.Value
                Sheets("Detail").Activate
                Application.EnableEvents = True
             End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this as well as IsNumeric(Target.Value), and still nothing happens when I click on any cells

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I've added a line below Target.Copy...: Sheets("Detail").Activate, hoping that when an invoice # is selected, the sheet will open as well, but it doesn't work, any thoughts?

Comment: I need to see the full sub